# Add parallax to ion tab content scroll

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to implement parallax on a single page tab, with an static top content (this should be hide on scroll), and the content is served using a page (this contains a list)

the ion-tab code:

```
<ion-tabs class="section">
<ion-tab [root]="tab_product" tabTitle="Productos" tabIcon="ios-cube-outline"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab  tabTitle="Vacantes" tabIcon="ios-briefcase-outline"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab  tabTitle="Cupones" tabIcon="ios-pricetags-outline"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab  tabTitle="Informacion" tabIcon="ios-information-circle-outline"></ion-tab>
```

[image]

using this article [High Performance Parallax Animation in Ionic 2](https://www.joshmorony.com/high-performance-parallax-animation-in-ionic-2/). I can't add the class who trigger the parallax because the tab content is placed after my top static content which will be pulled up on scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Finally 
In each Page which is placed by the Tabs, I had to copy the content with Parallax and the scroll content using the class to set the parallax content, used in the Tutorial link.

Example:

In the page:

```
<ion-content elastic-header="">
  <div class="background-image">
    <!--The parallax content-->
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
  <!--The scroll content-->
</ion-content>
```